# AWS Secret Manager Update

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

Is there any possible method by which i can update key/values in AWS Secret Manager without having to retrieve the current values and then updating them?

The current solutions i have found first retrieve the value from secrets manager:

```
original_secret = client.get_secret_value(SecretId="my_first_secret")
```

Then do an update on them and run the update-secret command:

```
updated_secret = original_secret.update({"UPDATE_KEY": "update_value"})
client.update_secret(SecretId="my_secret_name", SecretString=json.dumps(updated_secret))
```

But i dont want to retrieve the secret values.
Preferred language is python.

Comment: What do you mean by "update"? Does it involve knowing the current contents (eg appending data), or do you merely wish to **replace** an existing entry (with the new value having no relationship to the existing value)?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: @AdityaNair have you found a solution yet? I am also in need to find a way to update a single record of the key/value from the Secret without the need of fetching the entire load.

Comment: @azngunit81 That's how it is done, as I explain in my answer.

Comment: If there is no other way i'll have to accept Marcin's answer by end of the bounty period as currently i'm using that solution. @azngunit81

Comment: @AdityaNair no choice - accepted on my side too

Comment: okay...i'm going with Marcin's solution then @azngunit81

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly you **can't do this**, as secrets values are de-facto **immutable**. Instead what you call an "update" is just a process of  [creating](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/manage_update-secret.html) a **new version** of the secret:

> When you update the encrypted secret value in a secret, **you create a new version of the secret**. The new version automatically receives the staging label AWSCURRENT.

AWS console dumps down this process, as it make it appear that you can "update" a secret's value in-place. Instead it just copies the current version, updates its value, and creates a new version of the secret's value. All this is done in the backend, so you don't see this.

But using AWS CLI, you can **list the secret value versions** with [list-secret-version-ids](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/list-secret-version-ids.html). If you do this, you will see that you never update any secret values directly, you just keep creating new versions of it with a past value still present (only one past value is kept). You can always retrieve the old version using `--version-id` in [get-secret-value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/secretsmanager/get-secret-value.html).

So you have to do the same with python. Get the current version of the secret's value, update it locally, and make a new version of the value.

Comment: Ok so because it is immutable, AWS itself is doing this in the background, hence why you need to download it yourself and that the entire key/value entry  must be done in whole.

Comment: @azngunit81 Yes.  AWS console does not show version of your secret's values. But you can check the versions using AWS CLI. After each update in console, you will get AWSCURRENT version (your new one), and the previous version.

Comment: @AdityaNair No problem. Glad it helped:-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`put_secret_value()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/secretsmanager.html#SecretsManager.Client.put_secret_value):

```py
import boto3
client = boto3.client('secretsmanager')

# Create secret
client.create_secret(
    Name='foo',
    SecretString='bar'
)

# Update secret
client.put_secret_value(
    SecretId='foo',
    SecretString='bar2'
)
```

Comment: I want to replace the secret value for a secret key under the particular secret Id. This will just replace the entire secret key/value pairs with bar2 right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you are saying that your `SecretString` is a JSON object and you only want to replace one element of that JSON, then I think you would need to replace the whole JSON. The Secrets Manager is not aware of the format of the string -- it just sees it as a single string. Therefore, the code in your question would be the way to do it.

Comment: Yes thats what i'm trying to find...its just that credentials being retrieved is not so safe...never mind

Comment: `SecretString` will override the entire element inside the secret, the only way so far is to fetch first and then update (or append) an element from the json. So far no known solutions